# Hooking into bootstrap modal close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using AngularJS (and can't use the Angular Bootstrap Modal) and am trying to hook into the hidden event for when my modal is closed.

```
angular.element('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log('closed');
});
```

I cannot get this function to run.  I noticed that in the `angular.element` docs it says `on()` - Does not support namespaces, selectors or eventData.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: are you using full jQuery or just relying on the jqLite?